# What is the definition of affective cueing?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, terminology, emotion

In contrast to **affective priming**, what is **affective cueing**? I'm not sure how to differentiate between the two.

I found a good review on affective priming in [Karl Christoph Klauer (1997)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14792779643000083) in the European Review of Social Psychology, and from this I gather that affective priming simply is a priming which is targeted at emotions instead of at reactions. I did not find any definition of affective cueing so far. The best I could manage was from [this question](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101121005222AA12gP3), however it does not help me at all, nor do the reference in there.

Answer (score 5):

There is no agreed-upon definition of **affective cueing** because it's not a proper name. If you google for "affective cueing" you only find a handful of hits and in them the term is used differently, mostly to indicate that some cue (a stimulus that carries information) is of positive versus negative valence.

In contrast, **affective priming** refers to a specific, experimental research paradigm:

> Affective priming investigates whether the evaluation of a first stimulus, the prime, that is to be ignored, affects the processing of subsequent stimuli.

(as described in the [article](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14792779643000083) you found)